# Derive random output from payload & encryption key and verify it without knowing the payload

Tags: encryption, hash

I want to know if this type of hashing or encryption scheme exists.

---

Let's say there is a `master key : 'abcdefg'`

I want to encrypt the `payload : '2018-11-08 22:11:02'`

---

The `output : 'A12B34C45D56E7FG6H'` is random, whether payload is the same or not.

No one can derive the `payload` from the `output` without the `master key`.

I know the `master key`, but I don't know the `payload`.

Using the scheme, I can derive `payload` from the `output` using the `master key`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but this sounds like a typical symmetric encryption (i.e. AES and similar) with a random initialization vector: output looks random and due to the random IV is always different even if the payload and master key stay the same, payload can only be reconstructed by having output and master key. Note that hashes are not suitable for this since they are one-way and also reduce the information, i.e. they can not be used to restore the original content.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think the comment would be more clear without mention of an IV since none is in the question. With or without an IV AES encrypted data appears random and is secure if the key is unknown.

Comment: @zaph: without a random IV same payload and master key will result in same output which the OP seems to like to avoid. At least a previous version of the question seemed to imply this.

Comment: Yes, but not part of the question: *"No one can derive the payload from the output without the master key"*. I think a little more is being read into the question that the OP intends given the level of the question.

Comment: @zaph I would like to avoid getting same outputs for same payloads.

Comment: You need to provide a random input, such as a random IV, if you want a random output from an identical key and payload. If you need to be able to verify the encrypted data you need authentication, some choices are encrypt and then MAC with another key (possibly derived from the encryption key) or authenticated encryption such as AES in GCM mode.

Comment: @zaph If i add a salt or a nonce, shouldn’t I remember it(i.e. store it on a db)?

Comment: The random IV does not need to be secret for encryption and can generally just prefix the encrypted data. But the problem is I have no idea what you are trying to do? You start be wanting random output. Then want to verify it but verify what? it is nit clear if you want random data or to encrypt data to later be decrypted. There is the keyword `hash`, what does that have to do with the question? IOW, what are you trying to accomplish? Please edit the question with full information and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MoonsikPark, I believe what you are looking for is called [Authenticated_encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption)